# Any way to get VMware Fusion's Shared Folders working with 11.04/Natty guest?

Tags: 11.04, vmware, vmware-fusion

Just upgraded to Natty this morning. I know, I should have waited until VMware updated Fusion for it, but I was impatient. :-) I can't seem to get Shared Folders working now... anybody have this working, and if so, what's the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just managed it.

Some of the VMware Tools modules supplied with VMware Fusion 3.1.2 seem to have problems compiling under 11.04. I'm a programmer, but rather than trying to fix them (which could become a huge time-sink), I thought I'd try the `open-vm-tools` package, since that's available for 11.04 and should be essentially a precompiled version of the same thing.

It didn't work at first, but I found [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools#Installing%20VMware%20tools%20on%20an%20Ubuntu%20guest) describing the proper way to install them -- you apparently have to install `open-vm-dkms` first (not sure why, I'd think it would auto-install as a dependency, but it didn't). After that, install `open-vm-tools`. Then in the VMware Fusion settings, turn **OFF** Shared Folders, then turn them back on.

After that, my shared folders appeared in `/mnt/hgfs` as normal. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Read [this blog](http://blog.breadncup.com/2011/02/26/vmware-tool-patch-for-linux-kernel-2-6-3738/) for solutions to VMware Tools compilation errors under Ubuntu 11.04 and VMware Fusion 3.1.2

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.